# How to make AgGridReact rows lower z-index

Tags: ag-grid-react, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I have a cell renderer that shows an mgt-person fine but the hover mgt-person-card goes behind the following ag-rows.
[image]

I tried

```
.ag-row {
     z-index: -unset !important;
}
.ag-cell {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

and

```
mgt-person-card {
   z-index: 100000; 
}
```

Also `suppressRowTransform={true}`

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm encountering a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for a cell renderer, but I had a similar issue with a cell editor with a custom drop down.  The issue occurred after I upgraded from ag-Grid version 24 to version 27.  I didn't need to set suppressRowTransform to true or tinker with the CSS to fix it.  Instead, in the column definition where I am using the cellEditor I added the property cellEditorPopup and set it to true.

Comment: , cellEditorPopup :true did not work for me but thank you.